# C Looping a switch?

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

so here is my code:

My problem is that I want to loop the switch statement with a while loop, depending on what char response gets (at the bottom).

I have tried putting the whole switch statement in a do while loop (that flopped).

Anyways I'm new to this language and I wanted to try to make a complex program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LINE  "____________________"
#define TITLE "Tempature Converter"
#define NAME  "Jose Meza II"

char scale, response;
float temp, celTemp, farTemp, kelTemp;

int main() {

printf("\n \t %s \n \t %s \n", LINE, TITLE );
printf("\t by %s \n \t %s \n\n", NAME, LINE );

printf("Enter C for Celsius, F for Fahrenheit, or K for Kelvin: ");
scanf("%c", &scale);
printf("Tempature value: ");
scanf("%f", &temp);

switch (scale)
{
    case ('c'): /* convert to Fahrenheit and Kelvin */
    {
        farTemp = (temp * 9 / 5) + 32;
        kelTemp = temp + 273.15;
        printf("Fahrenheit = %.2f\n", farTemp);
        printf("Kelvin = %.2f\n\n", kelTemp);
        break;
    } /* end case 'c' */
    case ('f'): /* convert to Celsius and Kelvin */
    {
        celTemp = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
        kelTemp = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
        printf ("Celsius = %.2f\n", celTemp);
        printf ("Kelvin = %.2f\n\n", kelTemp);
        break;
    } /* end case 'f' */
    case ('k'): /* convert to Celsius and Fahrenheit */
    {
        celTemp = temp - 273.15;
        farTemp = (temp - 273.15) * 9 /5 + 32;
        printf("Celsius = %.2f\n", celTemp);
        printf("Fahrenheit = %.2f\n\n", farTemp);
        break;
    } /* end case 'k' */
    default: exit(0); /* no valid temperature scale was given, exit program */
} /* end switch */

printf("Enter in C to Continue, or S to stop: ");
scanf(" %c", &response);

return 0;
}
```

What can I do?

I have tried:

```
do
{
    printf("Enter C for Celsius, F for Fahrenheit, or K for Kelvin: ");
    scanf("%c", &scale);
    printf("Tempature value: ");
    scanf("%f", &temp);

    switch (scale)
    {
        case ('c'): /* convert to Fahrenheit and Kelvin */
        {
            farTemp = (temp * 9 / 5) + 32;
            kelTemp = temp + 273.15;
            printf("Fahrenheit = %.2f\n", farTemp);
            printf("Kelvin = %.2f\n\n", kelTemp);
            break;
        } /* end case 'c' */
        case ('f'): /* convert to Celsius and Kelvin */
        {
            celTemp = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
            kelTemp = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
            printf ("Celsius = %.2f\n", celTemp);
            printf ("Kelvin = %.2f\n\n", kelTemp);
            break;
        } /* end case 'f' */
        case ('k'): /* convert to Celsius and Fahrenheit */
        {
            celTemp = temp - 273.15;
            farTemp = (temp - 273.15) * 9 /5 + 32;
            printf("Celsius = %.2f\n", celTemp);
            printf("Fahrenheit = %.2f\n\n", farTemp);
            break;
        } /* end case 'k' */
        default: exit(0); /* no valid temperature scale was given, exit     program */
    } /* end switch */

    printf("Enter in C to Continue, or S to stop: ");
    scanf(" %c", &response);
}
while(response == 'c');
```

Comment: A suggestion: try to make a program simpler. not more complex.

Comment: Is this your homework? What *exactly* have you tried? Show me your tried do-while loop and we can see what you may have done wrong.

Comment: What is the fun in that (I'm 14 btw)

Comment: so no. not my homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>The most common way is to use a `do-while` loop. Make following changes</del>

<del>1. initialize `response` to `C`.
2. put the `switch` case and next `printf()` and `scanf()` in `do..while()` loop.
3. in the `while ()` condition, check `while (c == `C`)`.</del>

---

After the edit, the problem seems to be

```
scanf("%c", &scale);
```

you need to have a space before `%c`, like

```
scanf(" %c", &scale);
```

to avoid the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> [`\n`]after `C` at last.

Comment: Like C is, pretty interesting.

Comment: @el_coder just as the same reason for `scanf(" %c", &response);`